# Audio stops working, devices appear as "Dummy output" in 16.04

Tags: sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa

We help around 250 students with their Ubuntu computers (Dell 3380) We experience quite frequent audio problems in Ubuntu 16.04.

They come with an  Intel(R) Celeron(R) 3865U

The symptom is that audio stops working, both speakers and headset, and as device it lists **Dummy output**. There are several other posts in Ask Ubuntu about this topic.

My question is if anyone knows what is causing this problem? Is it handling, updates, settings, ... ?

We have a list of actions we do to solve this. Sometimes nothing helps, apart from reinstalling. Most suggestions here are found on Ask Ubuntu and other forums. You can see some of them are really desperate, but they all somehow resulted in fixing the problem in at least one occasion.

1. restart `alsa`

   ```
   sudo alsa force-reload
   sudo reboot
   ```
2. reset alsa driver state

   ```
   alsactl restore
   ```
3. remove pulse configuration

   ```
   rm ~/.config/pulse
   ```
4. disable audio in BIOS

   ```
   pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
   re-enable audio in bios
   reboot
   ```
5. re-install audio stack

   ```
   sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
   sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
   killall pulseaudio
   rm -r ~/.pulse*
   ubuntu-support-status
   sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
   ```
6. reinstall Ubuntu desktop

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   ```
7. switch secure boot in BIOS on and off
8. switch between UEFI and legacy boot in BIOS